# (In) no way? - She will agree to you leaving early in no way

Tags: adjuncts

A manner adjunct - **(in) no way**. It can move freely in a sentence.

> (In) no way will she agree to you leaving early.

But when **(in) no way** change its position, we can't drop **in**.

> She will agree to you leaving early **in** no way.

It seems very strange to me. How does grammar explain it?

---

**What I learned so far -**

From Jim and Fumble's comment what I learned is that my initial opinion was wrong. That manner adjunct here is not that free-moving. Now that they demonstrated it so well, I can clearly understand that my second sentence is really odd. Based on the position it shows the manner.

I want to edit my answer to provide another example sentence, and that doesn't seem as odd as my previous sentences was.

---

**First Edit -**

> (In) No way was it good. [CORRECT - *with or without **in***]
>
> It was good in no way. [*We can't drop **in** here*]
>
> It was in no way good. [*We can't drop **in** here*]
>
> It in no way seemed strange. [*We can't drop **in** here*]

Comment: It cannot move absolutely freely: # *She will agree to in no way you leaving early.* Your adjunct in #2 appears to give info on the manner in which she may leave early, not to *agree.*

Comment: What @Jim said. Except I must say I think *She will agree to you leaving early in no way* sounds completely ridiculous to me regardless of whether ***in*** is present or not.

Comment: @Fum Yes. We need to activate the contrivance generator to make even half-sense of #2. *I'll leave early in the sneaky way, or in the fast way, or in the secret way.* *She'll agree to you leaving in no way.* (?)

Comment: @FumbleFingers and Jim I edited my question to provide more example sentences.

Comment: @Man_From_India: I think you're on a hiding to nothing here. To repeat and amplify what I was getting at before, I personally don't like post-positioned negated forms like *It was good in no way* or *She will agree in no way* (though I've no problem with, say, *She will agree **completely***). But [***this no way***](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22but+this+no+way%22) justifies assuming that there's some *grammatical rule* allowing certain forms and debarring others. Anything said here is likely to be just one person's idiomatic preferences (i.e. - Primarily Opinion-based).

Comment: You forgot this: She will agree, in no way, to your leaving. "in no way" is a **set phrase**.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I disagree that anything said here is an opinion. There are observable patterns to in no way/in any way.

Comment: It follows the some/any/no patterns in fact. Sometimes, I wonder why I bother.

Answer (score 0):

There is an understood "There is" in front of "no way will she agree to you leaving early."

"(in) no way" is a compound colloquial expression.

The more grammatically correct version of the 2nd one is likely, "She will not agree to you leaving early."

Comment: (1) If the first sentence had been "[N]o way she will agree …," I would agree that it was short for "There is no way she will agree …" — but it is "[N]o way will she agree …," and "There is no way **will she** agree …" does not make sense.  (2) "No way" adds a level of emphasis that mere negation does not provide.  You can approach the meaning of the OP's second sentence with "She *definitely* will not agree …" (3) Arguably, the phrase should be "… agree to ***your*** leaving early …" — but that's another discussion.

Comment: [*In no way is this to be*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22In+no+way+is+this+to+be%22) *seen as a colloquial usage,*  unless you're *specifically* referring to the deletion of ***In***.

Comment: I fully agree that "no way" is a truncation of "there is no way," *not* "in no way." The sentence "No way she will agree to you leaving early" isn't truncating "in no way" to "no way" but is truncating "there is no way" to "no way." When I start off a sentence "No way," what's going through my head is "There's no way," not "In no way." If "In no way" is what I mean, then I say "In no way." I never truncate "in no way" to "no way." And it's not just me. Others here corroborate that. The question itself corroborates that, even underscores that, that being the clear explanation and answer.

Answer (score 0):

**In no way** is a set phrase, which means there was no manner in which.
compare: *in no way* to **in any way.**

- **In no way** did I agree with my boss. [notice: did I agree, an emphatic form]
- **In no way will she agree** to your leaving. [emphatic form with auxiliary and inversion]

It cannot be broken up.

- I did not agree with my boss **in any way**. Though one can put it in the middle:
- I did not, in any way, agree with my boss.

**Notice how** *in any way* and *in no way* are used with verb forms.

- In no way do I like what I see. [notice: do I like, an emphatic form]
- I do not like what I see in any way.

They both mean the same thing: When "in no way" comes first, it triggers an emphatic inversion and "in any way" has to come after the verb.

Of course, there is also:

- I agree with my boss in no way**. [no inversion or auxiliary]
- I do not agree with my boss in any way [no inversion, negative verb]

** not as much used.

None of this should be confused with the slangy: No way etc. Which is a shortening of: **there is no way** as in: There is no way that John will eat green beans. Same as: There isn't any way that he will.

Answer (score -1):

Simply put, “in no way” is a linguistically incorrect slang expression meaning “there is no way.”  “In no way will she agree” is an incorrect slang way of saying “There is nothing one can do or say to convince her to agree.”

Comment: slang? In no way did my boss agree to my leaving. Don't confuse the slang "no way" with "in no way" which is perfectly good English.